# bad file descriptor realted to threads

Tags: c, linux

```
/*Write a server application that does the following :
open 5 named pipes in read­only mode & read from each in a separate thread created in your process – meaning, one thread per named pipe ; main threadoes not read from a named pipe, instead joins all the threads and 
terminates; each thread uses its own individual buffer for reading data from 
a specific named pipe
*/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void* thread_routine1(void*fd1)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 while( (bytes_read = read((int)fd1,buff,20)) >0)
    {
     printf("%s\n", buff);
                   write(stdout,buff,bytes_read);
     //fflush(stdout);
    }  
    if(bytes_read<0){perror("error"); } 
    close((int)fd1);
}
void* thread_routine2(void*fd2)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 while( (bytes_read = read((int)fd2,buff,512)) >0)
    {
     //printf("%s\n", buff);
                   write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,bytes_read);
     //fflush(stdout);
    }  
    if(bytes_read<0){ } 
    close((int)fd2);
}
void* thread_routine3(void*fd3)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 while( (bytes_read = read((int)fd3,buff,512)) >0)
    {
     //printf("%s\n", buff);
                   write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,bytes_read);
     //fflush(stdout);
    }  
    if(bytes_read<0){ } 
    close((int)fd3);
}
void* thread_routine4(void*fd4)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 while( (bytes_read = read((int)fd4,buff,512)) >0)
    {
     //printf("%s\n", buff);
                   write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,bytes_read);
     //fflush(stdout);
    }  
    if(bytes_read<0){ } 
    close((int)fd4);
}
void* thread_routine5(void*fd5)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 while( (bytes_read = read((int)fd5,buff,512)) >0)
    {
     //printf("%s\n", buff);
                   write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,bytes_read);
     //fflush(stdout);
    }  
    if(bytes_read<0){ } 
    close((int)fd5);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t thid[5];
 int status,ret;
 int fd1,fd2,fd3,fd4,fd5;
    int res = mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo1", 0777);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("FIFO 1created\n");
    if(res<0)
    perror("FIFO already created");
     res = mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo2", 0777);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("FIFO created\n");
    if(res<0)
    perror("FIFO 2already created");
      res = mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo3", 0777);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("FIFO created\n");
    if(res<0)
    perror("FIFO 3already created");
      res = mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo4", 0777);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("FIFO created\n");
    if(res<0)
    perror("FIFO 4already created");
      res = mkfifo("/tmp/my_fifo5", 0777);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("FIFO created\n");
    if(res<0)
    perror("FIFO5 already created");
    fd1=open("/tmp/my_fifo1",O_RDONLY);
     perror("open status is");
     sleep(5);
    fd2=open("/tmp/my_fifo2",O_RDONLY);
         perror("open status is");
    fd3=open("/tmp/my_fifo3",O_RDONLY);
         perror("open status is");
    fd4=open("/tmp/my_fifo4",O_RDONLY);
         perror("open status is");
    fd5=open("/tmp/my_fifo5",O_RDONLY);
         perror("open status is");

      ret=pthread_create(&thid[0],NULL,thread_routine1,(void*)&fd1);
      if(ret<0)
      perror("error in thread create1");
  ret=pthread_create(&thid[4],NULL,thread_routine4,(void*)&fd5);
      if(ret<0)
      perror("error in thread create2");
        ret=pthread_create(&thid[1],NULL,thread_routine3,(void*)&fd2);
      if(ret<0)
      perror("error in thread create3");
        ret=pthread_create(&thid[2],NULL,thread_routine2,(void*)fd3);
      if(ret<0)
      perror("error in thread create4");
        ret=pthread_create(&thid[3],NULL,thread_routine5,(void*)fd4);
      if(ret<0)
      perror("error in thread create5");
     ret=pthread_join(thid[0],NULL);
         ret=pthread_join(thid[1],NULL);
         ret=pthread_join(thid[2],NULL);
          ret=pthread_join(thid[3],NULL); 
              ret=pthread_join(thid[4],NULL);
     ret=pthread_join(thid[5],NULL);
     }



    the above code for a process that creates a named pipe FIFO 
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   char buf[512],wr_buf[512]; 
   int ret,ret1,status;
   int npfd1,npfd2,npfd3,npfd4,npfd5;
   struct stat s1,s2;

  // ret = mkfifo(argv[1],0600);


   npfd1 = open("/tmp/my_fifo1", O_WRONLY); //opening the named pipe for reading
    npfd2= open("/tmp/my_fifo2", O_WRONLY); //opening the named pipe for reading
     npfd3 = open("/tmp/my_fifo3", O_WRONLY); //opening the named pipe for reading
      npfd4 = open("/tmp/my_fifo4", O_WRONLY); //opening the named pipe for reading
       npfd5 = open("/tmp/my_fifo5", O_WRONLY); //opening the named pipe for reading
                                    //only
   if(npfd1<0) {perror("error in opening the named pipe"); exit(1); }
 printf("enter someting into the buffer\n");
 bzero(buf,sizeof(buf));
 gets(buf);   
   ret1 = write(npfd1,buf,20);

     //printf("%s\n", buf);
                   write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,ret1);
     //fflush(stdout);

    if(ret1<0){ printf("nothing is there\n");} 
    close(npfd1);

   exit(0);

}
```

The above code is where i am creating the write end of FIFO. Now after running the two programs in different terminal i am getting a BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR error. when i try to write something to the first namedpipe ie. my_fifo1. Is it possible to pass the filedescriptor that is opened in main to threads the way i have done?

Comment: I've edited the post so that it's actually possible to read it now. Please take the time to post stuff that someone trying to answer it could actually read, and use correct grammar (even if English is not your first language, you should be aware that putting more than 10 question marks in a row is not how you end a question).

Comment: ok i wii take care the next time.

Answer (score 2):

Your `main()` function is passing a pointer-to-int, but your thread functions are casting that back to an `int` and then trying to use it as a file descriptor.  That's not going to work - you need to dereference the passed pointer in the thread functions (this is OK in this case, because those variables in `main()` are allocated one-per-thread, and `main()` doesn't exit until all the threads have finished).

```
void *thread_routine1(void *fd1)
{
 char buff[512];
 int bytes_read; 
 int fd = *(int *)fd1;

 while ((bytes_read = read(fd,buff,20)) > 0)

 /* ... */
```